# ExtJS - get full path of item

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have Ext.data.TreeStore. I use Ext.data.TreeStore. **Each node have unicue ID**.

I need something like that: when I select  node, I need to alert full path of it (I mean: my nodes id, its parrent id, its parrent id and root id).

for example if I click **childOf(2childOf(Root))** I need ids of [root,  2childOf(Root),  childOf(2childOf(Root))]

```
 ROOT
    1childOf(Root)
    2childOf(Root)
                  childOf(2childOf(Root))
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NodeInterface [getPath()](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-getPath), probably is what you want

```
getPath( [field], [separator] ) : String
Gets the hierarchical path from the root of the current node.

Available since: 4.0.4

Parameters
field : String (optional)
The field to construct the path from. Defaults to the model idProperty.
separator : String (optional)
A separator to use.

Defaults to: "/"
Returns
String
The node path
```

Here's a [small sample](http://jsfiddle.net/fxbxk/)

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
title: 'Simple Tree',
width: 200,
height: 150,
store: store,
rootVisible: false,
listeners: {
    itemdblclick: function( panel, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        alert(record.getPath('text','/'));
    }
},
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
```

});

Comment: can you give me an example?